# Find if parent is table

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to find out if an element is a child of a table and if so do not run script.

I was thinking something like this

```
jQuery(jQuery('li:has-parent(table)')) {
    // do this
} 
else {
    // do this
}
```

But the above doesn't work, any help would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (!$(element).parents('table').length){
   // if parent is not table
} else {
   // parent is table
}
```

"element" is your element selector.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ( $(element).parent('table').length ) { /* parent is table */ }
if ( $(element).closest('table').length ) { /* parent/N-parent is table */ }
```

---

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $element = $(selector),
        // You can use .closest if you are not looking for a direct parent.
        // http://api.jquery.com/closest/
        isChildOfTable = $element.parent('table').length;

    if ( isChildOfTable ) {

    } 
});
```

---

Just to add a [`.parents` vs `.closest`](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/jquerys-closest-parents/) discussion.

The problem with the [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-parents-vs-closest/20) is that it's trying to fetch the element rater then checking the length property. And the result is there fore not concluded in the tests:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
var parentTag = $(element).parent().get(0).tagName;
```

Check if `parentTag`  equals `table` or not

Comment: Note that `.tagName` most likely returns in UPPERCASE. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.tagName

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#child").is("table > #child")){

}
```

Comment: I would guess it would be faster to use `.parent('table')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('li').parent('table').length)
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't really helpful